# MVC 5 & Angular 2 Multiple "Siloed" Apps Structure Advisement

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc-5, angular2-routing

We have a large already existing MVC 5 ASP.NET 4.5.1 web application. The core concept since there are so many areas it covers, is that each page was it's own application. All the existing pages don't use anything besides JQuery, regular Javascript, and Handlebars templating.

Angular 2 seems very exciting, but I'm trying to figure out how exactly it will work with our philosophy. For example below is how our mvc routing serves up our separate apps currently...

Area/Controller1/Action1(App1)

Area/Controller1/Action2(App2)

Area/Controller2/Action1(App3)

etc.

Then we have separate API controllers to serve up our JSON data. From initial readings/learnings of Angular 2 I can't seem to wrap my head around how I would serve separate apps (since everything I can find always wants the index.html as the home, which makes sense if you really are making a SPA). Essentially, we're trying to continue development with multiple SPAs served up via this existing structure, not have to change older "legacy" apps on the site to use Angular until they are revisited individually, and figure out how to do the routing effectively.

Routing:
So an example in my head would be
`Area/Controller/Action(App)/routeUrlstuff`

I still want to be able to let them copy and paste that extended link and be brought back using the angular routing, instead of maybe just cutting off that URL and starting the angular app at it's starting point.

I don't really have any code to show, as I'm attempting to do a current project as a proof of concept that using Angular 2 from now on is viable for the application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently worked on a project which had similar concerns. We did thought about implementing multiple SPAs but in the end decided to implement one SPA with multiple modules.

I think we can extend that solution for multiple SPAs as well. Let’s look at a simple use case:

You want to create 2 SPAs

1. UserApp containing 2 modules (AddUser and ManageUser)
2. ProductApp containing 2 modules (AddProduct and ManageProduct)

You have following MVC controller actions that you want to use for above SPAs:

1. myApp/user/add
2. myApp/user/manage
3. myApp/product/add
4. myApp/product/manage

MVC controller actions 1 and 2 are to be used with SPA UserApp, routing to AddUser and ManageUser modules. Similarly, controller actions 3 and 4 are to be used with SPA ProductApp, routing to AddProduct and ManageProduct modules.

Conceptually this looks like:

[Multiple SPAs with multiple modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NiRQ.jpg)

### Angular Bundling:

I would leave the typescript transpiling and bundling to Angular CLI. If your project gets complex and you feel that the angular cli can’t handle your bundling needs, you can always eject webpack configuration.

There is a really good blog from [Yakov Fain](https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/) that you can look for configuring cli to bundle multiple SPAs. Basically you will be configuring angular cli to output your SPAs to different dist folders. In our case, let’s assume that these will be:

1. userAppDist for UserApp SPA
2. productAppDist for ProductApp SPA

### MVC Layouts:

To Load different SPAs on different pages, you will have to create different layouts or sub-layouts for each SPA.

Let’s Say: _userLayout.cshtml for UserApp

Inside _userLayout.cshtml, you will have to load your scripts from userAppDist folder

Something like this:

```
<main class="layout">
    <base href="/">
</main>

@*Now load scripts from userAppDist*@
```

Similarly you will have to implement layout for the other SPA loading scripts from productAppDist. Let’s say _productLayout.cshtml

### Routes:

To keep things simple you can match your server routes to angular SPA module routes. Otherwise, you will have to implement HashLocationStrategy on angular App.
Assuming you are going with the simple option, you have following views:

1. myApp/user/add --> AddUser.cshtml
2. myApp/user/manage --> ManageUser.cshtml
3. myApp/product/add --> AddProduct.cshtml
4. myApp/product/manage --> ManageProduct.cshtml

AddUser.chtml and ManageUser.cshtml will use _userLayout and will look like:

```
<user-app></user-app>
```

This is targeting UserApp SPA

AddProduct.cshtml and ManageProduct.cshtml will use _productLayout and will look like:

```
<product-app></product-app>
```

This is targeting ProductApp SPA

The MainAppComponent templates for these Apps will have

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

which will resolve to the angular module routes, based on the routes from the server. Now you have to match the routes in you angular Apps

Example for UserAppRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'myApp/user/add', loadChildren: 'userApp/modules/add-user/add-user.module#AddUserModule' },
  { path: 'myApp/user/manage', loadChildren: 'userApp/modules/manage-user/manage-user.module#ManageUserModule' }
];
```

Similarly, you will have to define matching routes for the product pages in product App SPA.

Hope this helps.

### Update: Configuration to avoid multiple route files

For above use case, there will be following controllers:

UserController with index action pointing to user/index.cshtml (using _userLayout) having following code:

```
 <user-app></user-app>
```

ProductController with index action pointing to product/index.cshtml (using _productLayout) having following code:

```
<product-app></product-app>
```

You will also need to modify you routeConfig.cs to include following:

```
routes.MapRoute("user", "user/{*catchall}", new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute("product", "product/{*catchall}", new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Above changes will force following behaviour:

1. Routes to myapp/user --> will go to user/index.cshtml
2. Also, any extended routes after myapp/user/blah/blah will still resolve to user/index.cstml

User/index.chtml spins up Angular User SPA and then angular routes will kick in. You will observe similar behavior from product route and product/index.cshtml as well.

Final route configuration on angular SPA user:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'user', redirectTo: 'user/add' },
    { path: 'user/add', loadChildren: 'userApp/modules/add-user/add-user.module#AddUserModule' },
    { path: 'user/manage', loadChildren: 'userApp/modules/manage-user/manage-user.module#ManageUserModule' }
  ];
```

The first route is default for user app. This maps to the MVC route myapp/user. Rest of the routes are not required to match MVC routes. You will have to do similar configuration on product SPA as well.

Comment: I'm trying this right now. Have you run into issues where you click the Back button on the browser after going from a SPA app to a completely different MVC route and SPA app sits there dead? Other than that, this looks very promising!

Comment: I think I'm close. If you have a sample app on GitHub, I'd REALLY appreciate it, I gave you the bounty points either way. Thanks!

Comment: You are going to have 1 route file for multiple SPA. Its bad design and solution. @SeanChase you cheat!

Comment: @SeanChase, Back button issue that you are describing is most likely due to routing configuration. It is hard to say what is wrong without looking at your configuration.
I also agree with the other comment that the simplest approach will require you to have route file for every module in a SPA.  The solution to this problem has already been posted by kemsky. I have updated my above answer to address this issue.

Comment: @Faiz-Mohamed-Haneef False. It is a single SPA with multiple modules. This is not a bad design, in fact it solves a lot of problems including a single output directory for Dist, 1 set of NPM packages, and a single framework for reusable components across multiple modules. How exactly is your solution better? And don't just give some weak description, let's see some code on GitHub before you starting accusing me of "cheating."

Answer (score 2):

From a solution architect perspective, I would recommend changes both on server side and client side.

To being with, lets say there are 3 apps
Area/Controller1/Action1(App1)

Area/Controller1/Action2(App2)

Area/Controller2/Action1(App3)

## 1. Identify SPA's

Develop angular SPA for `main` application. The view from the main application has links to Controller1. This should be a route in your angular SPA. However Controller1/Action1 should be a route not available in angular SPA. It needs to be requested directly from the server using html href links. This essentially means page reload.

## 2. Project Locations on Server

Once development is complete for different SPA's, generate the production build with compressed JS and index.html.

Place the different SPA under their respective folders. For example, /home/user/proj/Controller1/Action1 is a folder which has independent SPA

```
proj
-- Controller 1
---- Action 1
---- Action 2
-- Controller 2
---- Action 1
```

## 3. Webserver Configuration

Configure your web/app server. For example in nodejs. (IIS will have something similar)

```
# For Action SPA
location = /area/(.*)/(.*) {
  root /home/user/proj/$1/$2;
}
# For main SPA
location = / {
  root /home/user/proj;
}
```

where $1 will contain target Controller
and $2 will contain target Action

The index.html from /area/target Controller/target Action will be fetched and these Action are independent SPA of their own.

## 4. Summary

Different teams can work on Main, App1, App2 and App3 as independent deliverables with this approach.

Comment: Angular has a dist folder and routes relative to that, so how exactly is this conducive to mixing and matching with the SPA routing?  Do you have a working example solution?

Comment: Sure. I can setup something this weekend. If you notice, once URL is fired, the target SPA gets downloaded and the target URL gets routed from target SPA's 'base' path

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to configure MVC routing to map all possible urls for each controller to the same corresponding views i.e.:

```
routes.MapRoute("app1", "app1/{*catchall}", new {controller = "App1", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
routes.MapRoute("app2", "app2/{*catchall}", new {controller = "App2", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Each `Index.cshtml` will have its own script section pointing to corresponding angular app. So if you paste URL `app2/angular/dashboard/page` it will route too corresponding controller and view (`App2/Index.cshtml`), then when angular router kicks in it will open the rest part of URL `/angular/dashboard/page` page.

Then adjust base url and angular routing for each app, which it depends on your app structure.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to do the routing in Angular for the overall site. If you're already doing routing on the ASP.NET MVC side just keep it that way. Think of it as each page request is it's own angular application. That means each page has it's own ng-app in the body, and it includes it's own angular.js and whatever that app.js is as well. app.js will init angular and setup the controllers/components you use for that page only. Each page would do that. If you have multiple views within each app, then you can use angular routing for just those views for just that app. When a person clicks on a new app link, it uses ASP.NET server side routing to give the new page that will init angular, setup inter-page routing on client side for just that app, and setup controllers used by that app.

Comment: I’m asking about Angular (Angular 2/4) not AngularJS

Answer (score -4):

I am not sure if i got the whole image but will try to help by telling you how i do multiple SPAs with Angular.

In _Layout.chtml, you create the following

```
<body data-ng-app="appMain">
  <main>
     @RenderBody()
  </main>
</body>
```

In Home.chtml with above layout set, you write the following

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Models/HomeModel.js")" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/ViewModels/HomeViewModel.js")" type="text/javascript"/>

<div data-ng-controller="HomeViewModel" ng-init="">
  home view html content
</div>
```

In HomeController.cs you create the Index action that return the above

For routing and multiple modules, angular is very good on that. See another sample code below:

CreateAccount.chtml with above layout set.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Models/AccountCreateModel.js")" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/ViewModels/AccountCreateViewModel.js")" type="text/javascript"/>

<div data-ng-app="accountCreate" data-ng-controller="AccountCreateViewModel">
    html content
</div>
```

AccountCreateViewModel.js:

```
    var accountCreateModule = angular.module('accountCreate', ['common'])
        .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when(rootPath + 'Area/Controller/Action(App)/routeUrlstuff', { templateUrl: rootPath + 'Templates/redirectPage.html', controller: 'AccountCreateViewModel' });
            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: rootPath + 'Area/Controller/Action(App)' });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        });

accountCreateModule.controller("AccountCreateViewModel", function ($scope, $window) {

    // module scope code here
});
```

Each angular module has its own routing and business logic completely distinct from other modules. Each area, with its mvc actions (full page reload) and web api methods (JSON)) is now an SPA silo written in a very neat way.